# how to use the keys F1 to F10 in C code

Tags: c, character, action

I would like to know whether the user pressed F1 or F2 or F3 or F4 or F5 or ESC and perform an action after that but I don't know how to get these keys.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Take a look at this [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/46980/windows-keylogger-in-c)

Comment: The answer depends on what platform (such as Windows, Unix, Unix-like), and the type of interface (text terminal, graphical interface).  For each combination there are low-level and high-level library interfaces which can return a special key such as <kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>ESC</kbd> either as low-level (hardware) *events* or as high-level *symbols*.

Comment: i'll be using windows and a terminal for the moment can you give me a fonction i can use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Windows, there is the `_getch` function, which returns the bytes of a key code, one by one.  You can get a function key that way, detecting it by the presence of certain codes: `0x00` or `0xe0` as shown in the example in *[[C\C++] - how get arrow keys(correctly) using getch()?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a1759ad8-56d9-487d-84c9-3020300c87a3/cc-how-get-arrow-keyscorrectly-using-getch?forum=vcgeneral)*. When `_getch` returns one of those, the next byte is normally a *virtual key code*.

For making *sense* of those codes, the place to start reading is the [Keyboard Input Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468857%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), looking for *virtual keys*.  Microsoft provides a list here: *[Virtual-Key Codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)*

Some people might advise starting with `getch`, but Microsoft provides this only for *legacy* use (does not recommend its use in new programs due to conflict with POSIX, and provides [`_getch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/078sfkak.aspx) as the alternative).