# How to simulate a keypress

Tags: c, windows

I know about AutoHotKey but I want to make my own program for e.g. make it press F5 every 10 seconds. I searched the internet and Stack Overflow but did not find a solution

Is there a way to do it in C or not? I am using and targeting Windows 8.1

Comment: Using only standard C? Then no. Using the operating systems functions? Then yes. But since you don't tell us what operating system you're targeting it's really impossible to answer. Please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then edit your question to add more details and tags.

Comment: Will edit the question now. Thanks. I am using Windows 8.1 and targeting the same system.

Comment: [`keybd_event`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304(v=vs.85).aspx) or [`SendInput`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: Isn't `AHK` itself written in `C`?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk actually it is i managed to find a github copy of it tough its the old version

Comment: I think something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30518040/how-to-use-the-keys-f1-to-f10-in-c-code) used along with some timer routine can help you.

Comment: Could be helpful,thanks!

Comment: Did you take a look at Win32API?

Comment: Hmm not really but i think i can find my way with what Manjinder commented thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3):

You'd want to use the [`SendInput`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx) function. The following code sends a key-down, key-up pair of input events to Windows every 10 seconds.

```
#include <windows.h>

static const int delay_ms = 10000;

void sendF5(
    UINT uTimerID,
    UINT uMsg,
    DWORD_PTR dwUser,
    DWORD_PTR dw1,
    DWORD_PTR dw2) {

    INPUT input[2] = {0};
    input[0].type = input[1].type =
        INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    input[0].ki.wVk =
        input[1].ki.wVk = VK_F5;
    input[1].ki.dwFlags =
        KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    input[0].ki.dwExtraInfo =
        input[1].ki.dwExtraInfo =
        GetMessageExtraInfo();

    SendInput(2, input, sizeof(INPUT));
}

int WinMain(
    HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    PWSTR pCmdLine,
    int nCmdShow) {

    timeSetEvent(delay_ms, 1000,
        sendF5, 0, TIME_PERIODIC);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the key modular, check out my implementation (without event loop)

```
#include <windows.h>

const int key_a = 0x41;
const int key_b = 0x42;
const int key_c = 0x43;
const int key_d = 0x44;

write(int key) {

    INPUT inputs[2] = { 0 };

    inputs[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inputs[0].ki.wVk = key;

    inputs[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inputs[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;

    SendInput(2, inputs, sizeof(INPUT));
}

main() {
    // Some time to select another window here (e.g. Notepad)
    Sleep(3000);

    write(key_a);
    write(key_b);
    write(key_c);
    write(key_d);
}
```